# How can I go from Linux Mint to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere, so I'm asking here.  I simply want to go from my current OS, Linux Mint, to Ubuntu.  I recently left Windows 10 for this, but I very much regret it.  Ubuntu was probably what I was looking for.  So, what can I do?

Comment: You would like to do this *without* formatting and starting over?

Comment: I would re-install.  You can re-install without loosing your data files (ie. don't format your partition(s)) which is easiest. Mint use *artificially* higher package versions than Ubuntu (thus they can us Ubuntu repositories) making a re-install necessary. You didn't provide any specific release details, so this is *generic* advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu Live USB.
2. Leave everything default except for partitions.
3. Chose "something else" in the partition section.
4. Select root (/) and click "Change".
5. By default it will be "Do not use this partition", change it to ext4, check "format" as well.
6. Repeat 4-5 for /home but leave format unchecked. (This is to keep your data intact).
7. Continue with the installation.

I'm not giving every step in detail because you're experienced installing Mint. If you're not worried about the existing data. You can do a clean install as well.

If you're in doubt, leave your comments and we'd able to help.